# Minio Unable to initialize server switching into safe-mode: Unable to initialize config system: Invalid credentials

Tags: minio

I have minio with version
`minio version RELEASE.2020-04-15T19-42-18Z`

Certificates store in /etc/minio/certs:

```
ls /etc/minio/certs
CAs  private.key  public.crt
```

When run minio

**MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=4t4twr3r3rw3 MINIO_SECRET_KEY=ert4t4t43rwtw /usr/bin/minio server --certs-dir=/etc/minio/certs --address 0.0.0.0:9000 --certs-dir=/etc/minio/certs/ /var/lib/minio/**

Get error:

```
ERROR Unable to initialize server switching into safe-mode: Unable to initialize config system: Invalid credentials
```

How will fix?
Create issue on github minio? may be not corret my run command?

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the same issue.

Comment: I think i changed MINIO_ACCESS_KEY and MINIO_SECRET_KEY.

Comment: changing the minio_access_key and secret_key does not work for me

Comment: any hints to fix this

Answer (score 3):

If you can, try deleting the `.minio.sys` subdirectory in your data directory. That worked for me when I ran into this issue.